# Memory leak with ARC when returning a parameter object

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I have a strange (looks to me) and simple memory leak situation using ARC (automatic reference counting). I am working with iOS code, but I think it should apply to Objective-C in general.

I have a following function that returns the object assigned as a parameter after checking the properties of the parameter object.

```
- (id) returnParam:(id) obj
{
    // Do whatever filtering needed. Return nil for invalid input.

    return (NSNumber *)obj;
}
```

If I call this method in a loop as follows, I can see that the allocated memory keeps increasing until the loop ends in Instruments.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{        
    id obj = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i];        
    id obj2 = [self returnParam:obj];
    NSLog(@"attempt %@", obj2);
}
```

However, if I put the content of the `returnParam` function in the loop as follows, everything works fine. The memory foot stamp stays the same size all long.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{        
    id obj = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i];

    // Do whatever filtering needed. Break on invalid input.

    id obj2 = obj;

    NSLog(@"attempt %@", obj2);
}
```

I have eliminated the filtering part (so essentially the function only passes the object back to the caller), and the same situation persists.

Not understanding why this sequence does not decrease retain count as supposed, I tried all possible combination of `__weak`, `__unsafe_unretained` here and there, but none worked.

Can somebody explain why this (returning parameter object) doesn't work, and suggest me a solution of this issue?

P.S. BTW, it is not captured as a memory leak event in Instruments, but the situation as I consider is a obvious memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a leak. It has to do with how `-autorelease` works. Expanding on what `-returnParam:` does:

```
-(id) returnParam:(id) paramToReturn
{
   // make sure the variable is in the scope for the entirety of the function
   id returnValue = nil;
   @try 
   {
       // when the parameter is passed in, ARC will automatically retain it.
       [paramToReturn retain];
       returnValue = [paramToReturn retain]; // strong assignment (a = b)
       return returnValue;
   }
   @finally
   {
       [paramToReturn release]; // release the value we retained when we passed in the parameter
       [returnValue autorelease]; // autorelease the return value so it is still valid after the function exits.
   }
}
```

Now, let's compare this to your other loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    id obj = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] retain]; // retain, because 'obj' is strong by default.
    id obj2 = [obj retain]; // retain, because 'obj2' is strong by default

    NSLog(@"attempt %@", obj2);

    [obj release]; // release because 'obj' is strong
    [obj2 release]; // release because 'obj2' is strong.
}
```

Thus, your variables aren't getting cleaned up until the next autorelasepool is popped, which usually occurs at the next `NSRunLoop` tick in an iPhone app, or possibly at the end of the `@autoreleasepool` in a console application.

Comment: Did you try the above code in Instruments? I wouldn't be surprised if the code "just worked" if the optimizer is turned on, as long as both the method and the loop are ARC'd.  I also wouldn't be surprised if it still accreted memory in an autorelease pool...

Comment: @bbum isn't that what my answer said? `Thus, your variables aren't getting cleaned up until the next autorelasepool is popped...`

Comment: @Richard That makes sense. I was not understanding (or not thinking deeply enough) that ARC will be returning object by calling `autorelease`. So, probably it is an indication that I shouldn't call a function that returns an object (not necessarily a parameter object) when I have a `huge` loop. Or do you know any workaround to make that work?

Comment: @barley create your own `@autoreleasepool` around the insides of your loop. It's a fairly common solution in situations where major parsing is done, and can increase performance & memory footprint dramatically.

Comment: @Richard Ah, that is right. But I made the above simple case from  more complex case to understand the problem. In my real scenario, I am not calling the function from a loop, but calling from a delegate of [YAJL Parser](http://gabriel.github.com/yajl-objc/) while parsing a huge file. So, the whole loop is not contained in one function and thus, I don't think I can use the `@autoreleasepool`. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: @barley `@autorelasepool` can be put anywhere in code, it doesn't have to be one function to work. Try it, and see if your allocations decrease.

Comment: @Richard Hmm, I may be not understanding the `@autoreleasepool` very well then. I will dig into it a little. Thanks for help!

Comment: My suggestion was that this may actually "just work" as OP had written it if optimization is enabled, but fails when it isn't.   I.e. the compiler optimizes calls to retain/release/autorelease across call boundaries when calling from ARC code to ARC code (it will eliminate the autorelease, in fact).  But that may be an optimizer specific issue and the autorelease pool might still be necessary for DEBUG purposes, certainly.